# Load text from richtextbox to a 3 dimensional array to create an LMC IDE

Tags: c#, arrays, richtextbox

I am programming a project where I have to code a little man computer simulator. I have a richtextbox where the user will enter their lmc code. I would then like to load this into a 3 dimensional array to process the information. However I do not know how to go about this.

Comment: You should at least try to do something. Then provide us your code with sample input data, problem/error description, and expected output data

Answer (score 0):

you can load the richtextbox in a one dimensional array like this:

```
var richTextBoxArray = richTextBox1.Lines;
```

from there you could split each line of the one dimensional array into smaller strings with the split function. but im assuming that the user would give the lmc code in the the richtextbox like this :

5xx 3xx 2xx

when the user enters the code like this you could use space as an splitter:

```
char delimiter = (char)32;

var arraySplitt = richTextBoxArray[1].Split(delimiter);
```

the delimiter is the character you want a string to split by. space is (char)32
then you could fill your arraySplit into the desired 3 dimension Array.